# FluentAssertions factor out repeated config

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have unit-test code like this:

```
// version3 should be a copy of version2 with some differences
version3.Data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(version2,
  option => option
    .Excluding(x => x.Id)
    .Excluding(x => x.Status)
    .Excluding(x => x.Stale)
    .Excluding(x => x.Body)
    .Excluding(x => x.CreatedBy)
    .Excluding(x => x.UpdatedBy),
  "because version3 is version2 updated");
```

And then again

```
// version4 should be a copy of version3 with some differences
version4.Data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(version3,
  option => option
    .Excluding(x => x.Id)
    .Excluding(x => x.Status)
    .Excluding(x => x.Stale)
    .Excluding(x => x.Body)
    .Excluding(x => x.CreatedBy)
    .Excluding(x => x.UpdatedBy),
  "because version4 is version3 updated");
```

How can I factor `option` out?

I would like to make something like this:

```
// version3 should be a copy of version2 with some differences
version3.Data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(version2,
  option => baseOption,
  "because version3 is version2 updated");
```

And maybe even this:

```
// version3 should be a copy of version2 with some differences
version3.Data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(version2,
  option => baseOption
    .Excluding(x => x.OtherProperty),
  "because version3 is version2 updated");
```

Comment: declare the delegate external to the method call and append to it as needed.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. I haven't had much luck with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the option delegate externally as the base

```
Func<FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyAssertionOptions<MyDataType>,
    FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyAssertionOptions<MyDataType>>
    baseOption = option => option
        .Excluding(x => x.Id)
        .Excluding(x => x.Status);
```

And use it with the assertion

```
// version3 should be a copy of version2 with some differences
version3.Data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(version2, baseOption, 
    "because version3 is version2 updated");
```

For other assertion that needs to build upon the base you have to invoke the delegate and append additional options

```
// version3 should be a copy of version2 with some differences
version3.Data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(version2,
  option => baseOption(option)
    .Excluding(x => x.OtherProperty),
  "because version3 is version2 updated");
```

You should note that the current syntax being used has been deprecated in newer versions of the framework.

```
version3.Should().BeEquivalentTo(version2, baseOption, 
    "because version3 is version2 updated");
```

Answer (score 2):

Or switch to v5 so you compare your subject-under-test against an anonymous type where you only define the properties you care about for that particular test.

Comment: This feature simplified a lot of test cases.